# Enumerate NSArray starting at givven index searching both ways (no wrap around)

Tags: ios, arrays, nsarray, enumeration

Example. I've got an array with 15 objects. I want to start enumerating from a given index. Say start at index 5 and then the index above, the index under, above, under etc... I don't want it to wrap around, but rather stop and continue in unexplored direction.

So the order of indexes in my example would be. 
5, 6, 4, 7, 3, 8, 2, 9, 1, 10, 0, 11, 12, 13, 14

How can this be done?

Comment: Do you want it to "wrap around" the ends of the array, or stop and continue in the unexplored direction?

Comment: Goood question! For me I can only think of using the latter one (stop and continue in unexplored direction), but of course there would be use of the other one too. Maybe I'll open another question for that.

Comment: I've made an own post for wrap around: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14354514/202451

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a more compact implementation that doesn't require creating subarrays:

```
@implementation NSArray (Extensions)

- (void)enumerateFromIndex:(NSUInteger)index goBothWaysUsingBlock:(void (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))block
{
    BOOL stop = NO;
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < self.count && !stop; i++) {
        if (index + i < self.count) {
            block([self objectAtIndex:index + i], index + i, &stop);
        }
        if (i != 0 && !stop && i <= index) {
            block([self objectAtIndex:index - i], index - i, &stop);
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)enumerateArray:(NSArray *)array inBothDirectionsFromIndex:(int)startIndex
{
    for (int i=0; i<array.count; i++)
    {
        int index = startIndex;
        int indexAfter = startIndex + round(i/2.f) + (i%2 ? 0 : 1);
        int indexBefore = startIndex - round(i/2.f);

        if ((i%2 && indexAfter < array.count) || indexBefore < 0)
        {
            index = indexAfter;
            if (indexBefore < 0)
                index -= indexBefore + 1;
        }
        else if ((i > 0 && indexBefore > -1) || indexAfter > array.count-1)
        {
            index = indexBefore;
            if (indexAfter > array.count-1)
                index -= indexAfter - array.count;;
        }

        id item = [array objectAtIndex:index];

        //Do what you want with the item here

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It answers the question, but is not especially DRY and creating subarrays makes it less efficient than what it should be.

```
@implementation NSArray (Extensions)

- (void)enumerateFromIndex:(NSUInteger)index goBothWaysUsingBlock:(void (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))block
{
    NSArray *lastObjects = [self subarrayFromIndex:index];
    NSArray *firstObjects = [self subarrayToIndex:index];
    int currentIndex = 0;

    NSEnumerator *firstObjectsEnumerator = [firstObjects reverseObjectEnumerator];
    NSEnumerator *lastObjectsEnumerator = [lastObjects objectEnumerator];
    BOOL shouldStop = NO;
    NSUInteger numberOfIndexesEnumerated = 0;
    id obj = nil;

    while(numberOfIndexesEnumerated < self.count)
    {
        if (obj = [lastObjectsEnumerator nextObject])
        {
            NSInteger objIndex = [self indexOfObject:obj];
            block(obj, objIndex, &shouldStop);
            currentIndex++;
            numberOfIndexesEnumerated++;
        }
        if (shouldStop)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (obj = [firstObjectsEnumerator nextObject])
        {
            NSInteger objIndex = [self indexOfObject:obj];
            block(obj, objIndex, &shouldStop);
            currentIndex++;
            numberOfIndexesEnumerated++;
        }
        if (shouldStop)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Credits to @jalmaas for this answer