# Enumerate NSArray starting at givven index searching both ways (wrap around)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, enumeration, enumerate

Example. I've got an array with 15 objects. I want to start enumerating from a given index. Say start at index 5 and then the index above, the index under, above, under etc... I do want it to wrap around.

So the order of indexes in my example would be. 5, 6, 4, 7, 3, 8, 2, 9, 1, 10, 0, 11, 14, 12, 13

It would be great to have a method signature similar to following line, but I don't require that to approva an answer:

```
- (void)enumerateFromIndex:(NSUInteger)index wrapAroundAndGoBothWays:(void (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))block
```

How can this be done? Would like to avoid copying array etc.

At this post we do it with **no wrap around**: [Enumerate NSArray starting at givven index searching both ways (no wrap around)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14341488/202451)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borrowing from @omz, here is the wrapping variant, which is even simpler:

```
@implementation NSArray (Extensions)

- (void)enumerateFromIndex:(NSUInteger)index wrapAroundAndGoBothWays:(void (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))block
{
    BOOL stop = NO;
    NSUInteger actual = index;
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < self.count && !stop; i++) {
        actual += (2*(i%2)-1)*i;
        actual = (self.count + actual)%self.count;
        block([self objectAtIndex:actual], actual, &stop);
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: :) it is a bit hard to read, but it sure is nice and small! It seems very efficient!

Answer (score 1):

This is a mathematical problem. There is a nice solution. However, it involves sorting the list of indexes in advance.

The idea is to lay the integers from 0 to 15 out on a circle and taking the elements in the order they appear on an axis.

Since doing this in ObjC is so tedious, I present the python solution:

```
from math import pi, cos

def circlesort(N, start):
    eps = 1e-8
    res = range(N)
    def f(x):
        return -cos(2*pi*(x-start-eps)/N)
    res.sort( lambda x,y:cmp(f(x), f(y)) )
    return res
```

then

```
print circlesort(15, 5)
```

outputs

```
[5, 6, 4, 7, 3, 8, 2, 9, 1, 10, 0, 11, 14, 12, 13]
```

which is the desired result.

**EDIT**

Okay, here is a C implementation:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define sign(x) ((x)>0?1:(x)<0?-1:0)

void circlesort(int* values, int N, int start){
    double f(int x)
    {
        return -cos(2*M_PI*((double)(x-start)-.25)/N);
    }
    int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
    {
        return sign( f(*(int*)a) - f(*(int*)b) );
    }
    qsort (values, N, sizeof(int), compare);
}
```

This will circlesort an array of integers of lenght N. Use it like this:

```
int i, N = 15;
int indexes[N];
for (i=0;i<N;i++) 
    indexes[i] = i;
circlesort(indexes, N, 5);
```

Now the array `indexes` is sorted in the desired order. Because there are nested functions, you should add `-fnested-functions` to the compiler flags.

**EDIT 2**

Considering the fact that there is a much simpler solution (see my other answer) this one is rather academic.

Comment: Cool! Would be great to see a port of that to objective-c or c.

Comment: Hey, since you think it's cool and I think it's cool, I've invested half an hour to make the port to C.

Comment: I had to draw out what was actually going on. What a brilliant idea to put them out on a circle! Who would think of that!??!?!? So rad!!

Comment: I can always appreciate reducing a problem to a mathematical one whenever possible.